# How to setup WebStorm / IntelliJ so the output from Grunt console has links into the files, in the same way a FileWatcher that calls tsc would do

Tags: intellij-idea, gruntjs, typescript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Using IntelliJ/WebStorm if I run tsc from a FileWatcher, my compile errors are linked to the files in the editor, such that if I double-click on a compiler error, it opens that file and takes me to the offending line of code.

[image]

However if I run Grunt, either via the integrated Grunt console, or via a FileWatcher, the compile errors do not have links and I have to manually open the file and goto the offending line number.

[image]

Is there any way to get the compile errors comming from Grunt integrated as links, like the TypeScript FileWatcher's invocation of tsc does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Webstorm 8, it is not possible to apply regular expression filters on Grunt console output.

The way to go, as mentioned by lena, is to call Grunt directly via an External tool entry, and set up appropriate regex filters, such as:

For grunt-ts:

```
$FILE_PATH$\($LINE$,$COLUMN$\):.*
```

For grunt-tslint:

```
...$FILE_PATH$\[$LINE$,\s$COLUMN$\]:.*
```

Also see my comment above regarding a caveat for grunt-tslint in some environments.

Comment: I'm changing the correct answer to this one.  I am not currently in a position to test this to ensure it works as described, but if the nature of WS8 has fundamentally changed, other people looking at this thread should probably start here.

Answer (score 3):

When running Grunt as a file watcher, you can set up filters to make links clickable. You can use existing filters as example: open your file watcher settings, press Output Filters..., open the filter settings and copy the regular expression specified there. See http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/add-filter-dialog.html

Comment: This is working for me, but I'm confused about how to build the expression correctly.  If I simply put "$FILE_PATH$" into the expression field it links to the file, but I have not gotten the "$LINE$" bit to work yet, so it only opens the file but does not give me the correct line.  If my output looks like this "C:/_projects/GamesJS/SlotsDealWheel/src/SlotsDealWheel.ts(27,1): error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'asdf'"  what would be a good regular expression to include both the file path and the line number?

Comment: you can try $FILE_PATH$\($LINE$,$COLUMN$\): $MESSAGE$$

Comment: I've been trying all kinds of combinations of that, and none of them work.  In fact they break the $FILE_PATH$ part.  I was even trying things as simple as:  $FILE_PATH$($LINE$.

Comment: When using grunt and grunt-typescript, the messages are on a different line than the file path / line / column, and you also need to escape the parens (like the tsc filter does), so the filter that worked for me with grunt-typescript is >> $FILE_PATH$\\($LINE$,$COLUMN$\\):$$

Comment: @lena is there a way to make it work with relative path (to the current working directory of grunt/gulp). In other words, what should be the regexp for a message line like `app/script/controller.ts(11,45): 2304 Cannot find name 'abc'.`. I tried `$FILE_PATH$\($LINE$,$COLUMN$\): $MESSAGE$$`, and few others nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the '>>' added by grunt-typescript is throwing it off. Try grunt-ts (disclaimer : one of the authors) which is tested with webstorm https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts

Comment: The output from grunt-ts is still not linked into the source.  However I like grunt-ts better than grunt-typescript, so I'm switching out for it.

Comment: '>> ' is not throwing Webstorm off. After testing, it seems the issue comes from partial paths such as: ">> src/code.ts[10, 1]: expected...". One solution that works (at least in my environment):  prefix those paths by the root location, eg in your Gruntfile.js: files: { src: { [base+'src/**/*.ts']}}. Then, the following regex will work: ...$FILE_PATH$\[$LINE$,\s$COLUMN$\]:.*

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in Webstorm 9, the built-in Grunt console was filtering/linking on typescript compile errors with grunt-typescript. I am not sure if this is a recent change or not, but it was linking this for example,

[image]
So, I went into grunt-tslint/node_modules/tslint/build/formatters, and copied  proseFormatter.js to ./myproseFormatter.js. Then I tweaked it so the tslint output format would match the compile error format, by replacing square brackets with parens, and removing the whitespace between line and column number. Finally, I referenced my custom formatter in my gruntfile tslint config by adding the formatter and formattersDirectory properties:

```
tslint: {
  options: {
    configuration: grunt.file.readJSON('tslint.json'),
    formatter: 'myprose',
    formattersDirectory: './'
  },
  all: {
      src: [ 'app/**/*.ts' ]
    }
}
```

and it worked!

[image]